# Reading response data from TCppWebBrowser in Borland C++Builder

Tags: c++, c++builder, twebbrowser

How to I access the data returned on a web page using the TCppWebBrowser component in Borland C++Builder 6.0?

I have succeeded in posting data using the sample at:
http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/27519

Comment: One of my colleages has found an answer for me at:
http://cboard.cprogramming.com/cplusplus-programming/59957-tcppwebbrowser-question.html

This works very well.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to read response headers, there is no trivial way to do it. Check http://www.codeproject.com/KB/atl/vbmhwb.aspx, if you have Visual C++ you cam compile the code into an ActiveX and use it in BCB.